# How to customize Eclipse 4.5 theme?

Tags: eclipse, ide, themes

The selected items are too wide or too high, they want to change, in order to give a useful workspace.
OS: Linux Mint 17.3 Xfce 64bit

Eclipse:

Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Build id: 20160218-0600

[image: the problematic elements]

Answer (score 0):

I added these lines to eclipse.ini config file, and this is solved the problem!

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```